# Do all the solutions have to be in an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

An affine variety $V(X)$ is the zero-locus of a set of polynomials. So if the variety is generated by the polynomial $y-x=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then do all the solutions (i.e., every point satisfying $y=x$) have to be in $V(X)$, or could certain points, such as $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$ be omitted?

Comment: By definition, $V(X)$ means _all_ the solutions. It's perfectly ok to talk about open subsets of this set, e.g. $V(X)$ minus the origin, but you can't give those the same name!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I think that's an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by definition, $V(X)$ means all the solutions. It's perfectly ok to talk about open subsets of this set, e.g. $V(X)$ minus the origin --- the fancy name for such things is *quasi-affine varieties* ---  but you can't give those the same name!